# How can I replace a text in a div with my custom text with preg_replace or str_replace?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am having a wordpress widget that contains some html code for a div block. In that div, I have a text ie [year], that I want to replace with `<?php echo date("Y"); ?>`. But the problem is that I cannot use str_replace function for that since I have a whole div. So what I am doing is that I am trying to use str_replace but that is not working, Is there any way to do that, my code is as follows:

```
$date = date("Y");
ob_start();
$uwid = dynamic_sidebar('footer-copyright');
ob_end_clean();
$uwid = str_replace("[year]",$date, $uwid ); 
echo $uwid
?>
```

This is not working, but if there is  a way to do it with preg_replace, then it would possibly work, but I am not sure about the pattern.

Comment: What you have when you dump the `$uwid`?

Comment: This is result - string(1) "1"

Comment: No that is not regex, there I mean where there is exactly [year] in html then replace it with the current year.

Comment: Escape the brackets  with backslashes `'/\\[year\\]/'` (double backslash since one escapes the other in string literals).

Comment: Just edit the code in `dynamic_sidebar` instead. Why make it harder than it is?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi not with str_replace

Comment: @Andreas: Aah you're right. I mis-assumed it as preg_replace but you're right, that's not the case with simple `replace` :)

Comment: @quasi why are you recommending slashes/escaping with `str_replace()`.  I don't see regex being necessary here.  The error appears to be with the initial `$uwid` declaration.  Can't replace `[year]` in `1`.